# Why procedural musgrave texture gives different results when rendered and when baked?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I have created a nice procedural wood material for cycles (Blender 2.72).

The problem is that it looks very different when rendered and when baked. The baked result is very grainy and rough (invariant to number of samples which i keep the same for both render and bake).

[image]

It seems the problem comes from Musgrave Texture generator, which i use to generate the wood grain and vessels. I tested it alone, and the baked result contains much more grain and it misses many shades of grey compared to rendered result (note that the num. of samples is the same and all viewed 1:1).

[image]

I would like to ask if there is any trick how to get the baked result looking more similar to rendered result. Or is there any hidden sampling option which affects procedural generators while baking? Thank you

Comment: When Blender renders the result image, it also calculates all the lighting and evaluates all the procedural generators which I use to generate my wood pattern. The question is why the procedural generators give different result when rendered and when baked.

Comment: Yes, you're right; I confused something...

Comment: I had the same problem when baking occlusion maps. I had to switch to Blender render and then under the World tab, I needed to activate at least one of lightning features to enable "Gather" panel. The "Samples" parameter affects the baking operations. To temporarily switch over to Blender Internal Render to bake and then back to Cycles again didn't caused me any problems. I'm not sure if your texture will look exactly the same in Blender internal render though, but it would be worth trying.

Comment: Dalai Felinto said a while back on a thread about Cycles Baking that if the render does not match the bake then it is considered a bug.  I'd try a bake with OSL disabled just to make sure.

Comment: Finally I have replaced Musgrave Texture by Noise Texture, which gives much more consistent results. I have also found that the Musgrave Texture gives more inconsistent baking output as the Scale increases and Dimension goes to zero. I consider this as a bug of baking algorithm of Musgrave Texture and I hope it fill be fixed one day because Musgrave Texture provides more options than plain Noise Texture.